# HG: Importing changes from the diff of two repo

Tags: linux, shell, mercurial, diff

How could we manage to import into a hg repo the differences of two repos.

I mean, say we have repo A, A2 and B. I would like to import to repo B(same file structure than A) the differences between A2 and A (A2 is just A with some changes).

I guess we should generate a diff between both directories and use `hg import`, but how should the diff be generated?
is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If B is **totally equal** to A you can (in B) just pull from A2

If B also differ from A, you can:

- pull A from A2 (get additional head in A2 as result)
- save diff of heads in A2 into file
- import result of previous operation into B

And, BTW, you can streamline your current exotic workflow